# Swift 3 get attributes of textview sub string

Tags: swift, attributes, textview, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a textview which contains multiple paragraphs.  Each string can be formatted differently, for example some strings are bold and others using italicized fonts.

How would I get the attributes for a specific substring and get the attributes for the substring before that one?

For example I want to get the attributes for the selected text as well as the text that is displayed before it.

Here is what I have so far.

```
let range: UITextRange = textView.selectedTextRange!
let selectedText = textTV.text(in: range)
let previousRange: UITextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: range.start)!
let previousText = textTV.text(in: previousRange)
```

With this I was able to get the string that was selected by the user. As well as the text behind it.

However I don't know how to rip the attributes of that string out.

Comment: Use the text view's `attributedText` property.

Comment: This would return the attributed text for the whole textview wouldn't it? I need to get multiple attributed text properties as each string can have it's own attributes that differ from each other.

Comment: You can then use `attributedSubstring` to get a desired portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enumerate attributes and apply them for the new text:

```
textView.attributedText.enumerateAttributes(in: textView.selectedRange, options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { (attributes, range, stop) in
    // do what you need
}
```

Description:

> Executes the block for each attribute in the range. If this method is
>   sent to an instance of NSMutableAttributedString, mutation (deletion,
>   addition, or change) is allowed, as long as it is within the range
>   provided to the block; after a mutation, the enumeration continues
>   with the range immediately following the processed range, after the
>   length of the processed range is adjusted for the mutation. (The
>   enumerator basically assumes any change in length occurs in the
>   specified range.) For example, if block is called with a range
>   starting at location N, and the block deletes all the characters in
>   the supplied range, the next call will also pass N as the index of the
>   range.

Comment: This is super helpful. Definitely a push in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome. If it was really helpful, up-vote it please :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking for an attributed text for a given range, and you have a subclass of `NSLayoutManager`, you can call `textStorage.attributedSubstring(from: glyphRange)`. The `glyphRange` here comes from `enumerateLineFragments` method called from the subclass of `NSLayoutManager`.

Just putting it out there in case anyone needs this!